# Mac bluetooth not connecting when opening from sleep

Tags: macos, audio, sleep-wake, bluetooth, airpods

This issue popped up a month or two ago, but it's recently gotten much worse to the point where I am unsure of how to fix it and waiting is no longer an option.

I have a 15-inch mid-2015 Macbook Pro, model A1398, running macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

When opening my laptop, my airpod pros recently stopped connecting like they usually do when I put them in. Manually connecting bluetooth from the taskbar does nothing; there is no confirmation that it is trying to connect, no fails, it just does nothing. Same is true for connecting from system preferences.

It is unlikely that this is an issue with the airpods, as I can connect to any other device perfectly fine. Also, I have tried factory resetting the airpods, unpairing and repairing, turning off and on bluetooth, and restarting my computer, none of which have had any effect.

Things that occasionally worked in the past—albeit inconsistently—included quitting `mds`, `mds_stores`, `mds_sync`, `bluetoothd` and `coreaudiod` processes from activity monitor, and then attempting to reconnect the audio. However, these often didn't work and usually I would have to wait until the airpods suddenly connected after anywhere between 1-5 minutes. However, now, the airpods have completely stopped connecting altogether.

I have also tried all 3 debug options in the bluetooth taskbar `option+shift+click` menu: factory resetting all connected devices, resetting the bluetooth module, and removing all devices. Although this helps it connect a little faster sometimes when I go through all the steps, this has not solved the issue permanently and is an excessively long process just to connect a bluetooth device.

At this point, I am stuck. I have looked at all online resources I could find, most of which recommend resetting my airpods, disconnecting then reconnecting, restarting, and other things I've tried. If anyone has any suggestions on what I could do to fix this, please let me know. I will try them out and update my question with results on how well it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to reset SMC in your Macbook? Does your airpod pro works without any issue on your iPhone?

Comment: It works fine on my phone. I can try resetting SMC tonight and I'll let you know if that fixes it. Thanks!